# flutter workmanager does not send the http request

Tags: http, flutter-workmanager

I am using firebase messaging to send notification and I am using workmanager to send notification from background.But it does not send the http request.I have tried with other get and post request but it does not read the code beyond http request.

code to send notification:

```
     void sendNotification(String to) async {
        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        print("send notification called");
        print(to);
        String key =
            "";
        var data = {
          "to": to,
          "priority": "high",
          "notification": {
            "title": "Greeting",
            "body": "Hello there",
          },
          "data": {
            "message": "message ",
            "type": "msg",
          }
        };
        print("before http request");
        final response = await http.get(
            Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
            // Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
            // body: jsonEncode(data),
            // headers: {
            //   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            //   'Authorization': 'key=$key'
            // });
        );
        print(response.body);
        print("after http request");
        print("response${response.statusCode}");
      }
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    print("Task execution started");

    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "AIzaSyBwE5NLn-EkkoedtAUDymmAmKHhR2wNDhw",
          appId: "1:841467742007:android:61c3b6209fa48f15c73cb2",
          messagingSenderId: "841467742007",
          projectId: "messaging-bcc60",
        ),
      ).whenComplete(() {
        print("Firebase initialized");
      });
      print("After Firebase initialization"); // Add this line
      NotificationHandler().getToken().then((value) {
        print(value);
        NotificationHandler().sendNotification(value);
      });
      // final token = await NotificationHandler().getToken();
      // print("Token: $token");
      // print("first dem,o");
      // Demo();
      // print("fdec");
      // if (token != null) {
      //   Demo();
      //   NotificationHandler().sendNotification(token);
      //   print("Notification sent");
      // } else {
      //   print("Token is null or invalid");
      // }
      print("Notification sent");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error initializing Firebase: $e");
    }

    print("Task execution completed");
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

the notification is send when calling without workmanager